# Building in docker and deploying in ubuntu

Tags: docker

We are considering using docker for building (mostly golang and C++) but our production is not running docker, it is running ubuntu 16.

We are thinking of compiling the binary in docker and deploying it as is in production.

Is this advisable ? Are there any concerns we should be aware of ?

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 1):

Docker has almost no effect on the compilation process of your binaries, it just helps you to sandbox the tools and libraries you use. For your case, I advise you to use [ubuntu:16.04](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) as your base image for best similarity of your previous build environment. First concern would be whether your organization trust that official image or not, so that is one thing you should verify with your upper management.

You can even have a more stable approach by using Docker in production as well by building another container with compiled binaries in-place and minimal runtime libraries needed. This would help you to get almost same environment allowing different host OS other than Ubuntu 16.04. Beware that, kernels can still differ, so that is one of the differences to keep eye on.

Using Docker in production is more of a broad topic because you can either run it directly, use an [orchestration tool](https://kubernetes.io) or use a service like [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).